# Printing popup in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, printing

I am trying print a popup. I use Chrome, in other browser I am not interested.
This is my popup:

[image]

And this is my preview when I want to print it:

[image]

The question is obvius: How can I print only the contents of the popup?

PD: I have put angular tag because I use it. The way to call modal window (popup) is;

```
$scope.printPopup = function () {
        $scope.opManSel = this.dataItem;
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/OM_manager/printPopup',
            backdrop: 'static',     
            controller: 'printPopupController',
            scope: $scope
        });
    }
```

Good day!

UPDATE:
In my css i use:

```
.noprint { display: none; }
#print{
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And my popup has as id="print" and rest of elements has as class 'noprint', even so, background displays.

Comment: try to use CSS3 @ media print  to hide everything except your popup content.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some css to make only the popup print. If you want the page to print normally except when the popup is up, for example, you can add the following code:

In your css:

```
@media print {
  .noprint {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and then, in the printpopup function, you can add the class .noprint to the div containing everything but your popup (assuming your html is organized in that way; if not, the concept still applies). Make sure to remove the .noprint class when the popup is closed as well.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete info. Thx to comment!

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible for you to show more of your html/css in the question? With the given information everything should be working correctly.